# Safari not displaying images but Chrome works

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

I'm not sure why the images aren't displayed when the file is opened with Safari but displays the images no problem in Chrome.

I'm also having an issue with the logo.  I can't seem to place it correctly with the rest of the page. Im not sure if its padding or margin that needs to be adjusted but as it sits, the logo isn't sitting right

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="description" content="David Menard Front-End Ninja resume" />
<meta name="author" content="//David Menard">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimun-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
<meta itemprop="name" content="Udacity Portfolio course project">
<meta id="theme-color" name="theme-color" content="#307699">
<meta name="udacity-grader" content="http://udacity.github.io/responsive-images/project/project-grader.json" unit-tests="http://udacity.github.io/responsive-images/project/project-grader.js">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant|Cambay|Didact+Gothic" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css"/>


<style>
    @media screen and (min-width: 155px) and (max-width: 415px) {
        h1 {
            font-size: 4em;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h2 {
            font-size: 2em;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h3 {
            font-size: 2em;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h4 {
            font-size: 3em;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h5 {
            font-size: 1.5em;
            text-align: center;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        body {
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        .container {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .featured_title {
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        .col-4 {
            display: block;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .featured {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .logo {
            width: 100%;
            align-self: center;
        }
        .content {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .icon {
            width: 50%;
            padding-left: 6.5em;
            margin-top: 10em; 
        }   
        .col-4 {
            width: 100%;    
        }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 415px) and (max-width: 659px) {
        .wrapper {
            display: flex; 
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-around;
            align-items: baseline;
            align-content: space-around;            
            }
        .content {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            }
        .col-4 {
            display: inline-flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            width: 50%;
            }
        .logo {
            width: 10%;
            }
        .logo_text {
            width: 90%;
        }   
        .icon {
            width: 100%;
            padding-left: 60px;
            justify-content: space-around;  
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 2em;
            text-align: right;
        }
        h2 {
            font-size: 1em;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h3 {
            font-size: 1em;
            text-align: right;
        }
        h4 {
            font-size: 1.5em;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h5 {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .featured {
            width: 100%;
            display: all;
        }
        .wrapper {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 660px)  {
        .wrapper {
            display: flex; 
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-around;
            align-items: baseline;
            align-content: space-around;                
        }
        .content {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        .col-4 {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            width: 33%;
        }
        .logo {
            width: 50%;
        }
        .logo_text {
            width: 50%;
        }
        .icon {
            width: 15%;
            margin-left: 70px;

        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 2em;
            text-align: right;
        }
        h2 {
            font-size: 1em;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h3 {
            font-size: 1em;
            text-align: right;
        }
        h4 {
            font-size: 1.5em;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h5 {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .featured {
            width: 100%;
            display: all;
        }
        .wrapper {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 888px) {
        body {
            max-width: 888px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        .slideshow {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }

</style>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="logo">
            <img class="icon" src="img/icon.webp" srcset="img/icon.webp 2x, img/icon.jpg 1x" alt="udacity logo">
        </div>



    <div class="logo_text">

        <h1>JANE DOETTE</h1>
        <h3>FRONT-END NINJA</h3>

    </div>


    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;

    <div class="banner">
        <picture>
            <source srcset="img/slideshow_948w.jpg">
            <img class="slideshow" src="img/slideshow_948w.jpg" srcset="img/slideshow_948w.jpg 2x, img/slideshow_512.jpg 1x" alt="Picture of html script">
        </picture>

    </div>

    <div class="featured_work">
        <h4 class="homepage">Featured Work</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="col-4">
            <picture>
                <source srcset="img/Appify.jpg">
                <img class="featured" src="img/Appify.webp" srcset="img/Appify.webp 2x, img/Appify.jpg 1x" alt="Appify logo">

            <div class="featured_title">
                <h2>APPIFY</h2>
                <h5>https://github.com/udacity/Appify/</h5>
            </div>
            </picture>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
            <picture>
                <source srcset="img/sunflower.jpg">
                <img class="featured" src="img/sunflower.webp" srcset="img/sunflower.webp 2x, img/sunflower.jpg 1x" alt="Picture of sunflower">

            <div class="featured_title">
                <h2>SUNFLOWER</h2>
                <h5>https://github.com/udacity/Sunflower/</h5>
            </div>
            </picture>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
            <picture>
                <source srcset="img/Bokeh.jpg">
                <img class="featured" src="img/Bokeh.webp" srcset="img/Bokeh.webp 2x, img/Bokeh.jpg 1x" alt="light distorsion">

            <div class="featured_title">
                <h2>BOKEH</h2>
                <h5>https://github.com/udacity/BOKEH/</h5>
            </div>
            </picture>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
</div>
</body>
<footer>
</footer>    
</html>
```

Here is the CSS file

```
body {
    font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Cambay', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Assistant', sans-serif;
}

.container {

    display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: baseline;
    align-content: space-around;
    width: 100%;
}
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: baseline;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

/* We tell all items to be 100% width */



img, embed, object, video {
    max-width: 100%;
}


.bar {
   width:100%;
   height: 5px;
   background-color:#7d97ad;
}
.featured_work {
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.col-4 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you asked the wrong question you are not using images like (jpg, png etc) you are using webp

and according to **caniuse.com** webp is not supported by all browser see http://caniuse.com/#feat=webp

it only supported by browsers which uses chrome engine like chrome, opera(new), android browser etc

also see https://optimus.keycdn.com/support/webp-support/ for better understanding